# how to custom sort in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I new in nodejs,use mongoose to find doc,then i has a sort demand,

`var model = new mongoose.Schema({name:String,field1:Number,field2:Number});`

dose i can sort by `field1-field2`?

e.g. `model.find({}).sort(function(a){return a.field1-a.field2;})`

but mongoose now i only `sort(field1,1) or sort(field2,1)`.

Dose mongoose support custom sort? thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your sort commands as argument like this:

```
model.find({}).sort('field', 1, 'field2', -1)
```

where 1, -1 are ASC, DESC, respectively.

Comment: thanks,but this is not what my want.It sort field1 first then sort field2 when field1 has same.I want sort by 'field1-field2'.Now I solution is add field3 to store field1-field2 value when field1 or field2 has changed.